# Possible race condition when loading data generated by PHP in an Android app

Tags: php, android

I'm writing an app that deals with sales data.  The data is outputted to a private webpage, which my app can access and read.  However, my app does not always receive all of the data that it's supposed to.  (If I open the webpage in a desktop browser, the data is always complete)  I suspect that this may be due to a race condition in which the app tries to read the data on the webpage before the webpage has loaded completely.  Here is the code that reads the data from the webpage:

```
     try {
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(120000 /* milliseconds, or 2 minutes */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(120000 /* milliseconds, or 2 minutes */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            // Convert the InputStream into a string
            String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
            return contentAsString;

            // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
            // finished using it.
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            } 
        }
```

As you can see, I added a Thread.sleep() to give the page time to load, and this has helped, but has not solved the issue completely.

What can I do to make sure that the app waits until the webpage has loaded completely before trying to read data from it?

Edit: Here is my readit function:

```
public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Reader reader = null;
        reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");        
        char[] buffer = new char[len];
        reader.read(buffer);
        return new String(buffer);
    }
```

Edit 2: I have edited readIt to loop until a certain character sequence is found in the buffer.  This works, but if the data doesn't load quickly enough, then the app will crash because Android thinks that there's an infinite loop.  Here is the edited code:

```
    public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        boolean xyz = false;
        Reader reader = null;
        char[] buffer = null;
        while (xyz == false){
            reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");        
            buffer = new char[len];
            reader.read(buffer);
            String test = new String(buffer);
            System.out.println(test);
            if (test.contains("@@@")){
                xyz = true;
            }
        }
        return new String(buffer);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, the code I am using extends asynctask.

Comment: post `readIt(is, len)`

Comment: you are doing the wrong assumption that the data all available when you read from stream

Comment: Okay, so how do I make sure that the data is available when I read from the stream?  That is exactly what I was asking in my original question.

Comment: you should loop on the stream, until read returns a value less than 0, appending the data read at each iteration to your string

Comment: Wait, that won't work.  When the data is incomplete, readIt reads a bunch of gibberish until it reaches len.  The gibberish is similar to what you'd get if you forgot to null-terminate a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's what I found that worked.  The issue was that the reader would read from the stream even if the stream wasn't fully loaded.  It would also read 1000000 characters from the stream, even if there weren't that many characters to be read.  This caused the reader to read whatever was available, and then fill in the rest of the 1000000 characters with UTF-8 unknown symbols (�).  The code that you see here loops on the stream, each time reading whatever has loaded since the last loop, and discarding the � characters.  It does require that whatever you are reading not contain any non-UTF-8 characters, because it splits the string on the first � that it finds, but if you are reading in UTF-8, you should make sure of that anyway.  It also requires that you place an uncommon sequence of characters at the end of your data to mark the end.

```
// This converts the data stream into a String that can be manipulated.
    public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        boolean isDone = false;     // Boolean to keep track of whether the data is loaded or not.
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");     // Input stream reader
        char[] buffer = null;       // Character array to hold the data from the stream
        String readDump = null;     // String to hold data converted from the character array, which will most likely contain junk characters.
        String splitDump [] = null;     // String array that holds the valid data and junk from readDump after they've been separated.
        String dataHolder = "";     // Output string that holds the valid data
        // While the final characters have not been read (@@@)
        while (isDone == false){        
            buffer = new char[len];
            reader.read(buffer);        // Read data from the stream
            readDump = new String(buffer);      // Turn it into a string
            splitDump = readDump.split("[\\x00\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F]", 2);     //Split the string into valid data and junk.
            dataHolder += splitDump[0];     // Add the valid data to the output string
            System.out.println(dataHolder);     //Debug
            if (dataHolder.contains("@@@")){
                // If the output string has the final characters in it, then we are done.
                isDone = true;
            }
        }
        return dataHolder;
    }
```